# Grepping string, but include all non-blank lines following each grep match

Tags: text-processing, grep

Consider the following toy example:

```
this is a line 
this line contains FOO 
this line is not blank

This line also contains FOO

Some random text

This line contains FOO too
Not blank 
Also not blank

More random text 
FOO!
Yet more random text
FOO!
```

So, I want the results of a grep for FOO, but with the extra wrinkle that lines following the matching lines should be included, as long as they are not blank, and they do not themselves contain FOO. So the matches would look as follows, with the different matches separated:

MATCH 1

```
this line contains FOO 
this line is not blank
```

MATCH 2

```
This line also contains FOO
```

MATCH 3

```
This line contains FOO too 
Not blank 
Also not blank
```

MATCH 4

```
FOO!
Yet more random text
```

MATCH 5

```
FOO!
```

Bonus points (metaphorically speaking) for a simple single line script that can be run on the command line.

ADDENDUM: Adding a running count of the match number would be quite handy, if it is not too hard.

Comment: do you want all the Matches in one output or you want them to be ran separately ?

Comment: I guess one output is fine, as long as they are clearly separated, say by a blank line.

Comment: might not possible in one output but I can try to see in each separate output!

Comment: For matches 4 & 5, the simple logic could say "I've matched (the 4th) "FOO", so I should continue printing in this matching block until I see a blank line, and so the final "FOO" is included in this block", but i see you've separated it -- because it's a separate "FOO" match. Do you require the 5th "FOO" to be printed separately?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, please separate different FOO matches.

Comment: I think at this point.. needs more clarification.

Comment: I'm not a Perl guru, but isn't there a paragraph mode that's applicable here?

Comment: The fast-and-dirty approach is simply `grep -A 1 FOO`, then (automatically) ignore blank trailing context lines in the output. Doing this exactly seems to require storing state, which requires `awk/perl`.

Comment: -1, it would be helpful to see what you’ve tried yourself.

Answer (score 9):

Using `awk` rather than `grep`:

```
awk '/FOO/ { if (matching) printf("\n"); matching = 1 }
     /^$/  { if (matching) printf("\n"); matching = 0 }
     matching' file
```

A version that enumerates the matches:

```
awk 'function flush_print_maybe() {
         if (matching) printf("Match %d\n%s\n\n", ++n, buf)
         buf = ""
     }
     /FOO/ { flush_print_maybe(); matching = 1 }
     /^$/  { flush_print_maybe(); matching = 0 }
     matching { buf = (buf == "" ? $0 : buf ORS $0) }
     END   { flush_print_maybe() }' file
```

Both `awk` programs uses a very simple "state machine" to determine if it's currently matching or not matching.  A match of the pattern `FOO` will cause it to enter the `matching` state, and a match of the pattern `^$` (an empty line) will cause it to enter the non-`matching` state.

Output of empty lines between matching sets of data happens at state transitions *from* `matching` (either into `matching` or into non-`matching`).

The first program prints any line when in the `matching` state.

The second program collects lines in a `buf` variable when in a `matching` state. It flushes (empties) this after possibly printing it (depending on the state), together with a `Match N` label at state transitions (when the first program would output an empty line).

Output of this last program on the sample data:

```
Match 1
this line contains FOO
this line is not blank

Match 2
This line also contains FOO

Match 3
This line contains FOO too
Not blank
Also not blank

Match 4
FOO!
Yet more random text

Match 5
FOO!
```

Comment: Nitpicking, these output an extra blank line if there’s a non-matching section at the end of the input ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes. It will. Each result block will be terminated by an empty line.

Comment: Only if there’s an empty line following the result block (so the example text in the question doesn’t cause an empty line to be printed at the end).

Comment: @StephenKitt It's almost midnight here, I'll get back to it later.   :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
sed -ne '/FOO/{x;P;x};/FOO/,/^$/p' testfile
```

Each block of non-empty lines in the output is a single chunk of matched data from the input. The number of newlines varies.

This

1. suppresses output (`-n`); then
2. prints a blank line before every occurrence of "FOO" (`/FOO/{x;P;x}` - uses the empty hold space);
3. selects ranges of lines starting from ones containing FOO (`/FOO/`) and ending on empty lines (`/^$/`); and finally
4. prints those lines (`p`).

---

```
this line contains FOO
this line is not blank


This line also contains FOO


This line contains FOO too
Not blank
Also not blank


FOO!
Yet more random text

FOO!
```

Answer (score 5):

I don’t think this is doable with `grep`, but it is with AWK:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

/FOO/ {
  matched = 1
  if (notfirst) print ""
  notfirst = 1
}

/^$/ {
  matched = 0
}

matched
```

With a count of matches:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

/FOO/ {
  matched = 1
  if (matches) print ""
  printf "Match %d\n", ++matches
}

/^$/ {
  matched = 0
}

matched
```

In both cases, the first two blocks determine whether the current record should be copied to the output. When the current record matches “FOO”, the first block sets `matched` to 1, outputs a blank record if necessary (to separate the forthcoming output from the previous match); in the second variant, it also increments the `matches` counter and outputs a header. When the current record is empty, the second block sets `matched` to 0. The lonely `matched` condition prints the current record if `matched` is 1.

Answer (score 2):

I've included a `pcregrep` solution and a `python` solution.

### Multiline Grep Solution

If you have `pcregrep` installed, you could use a multiline pattern, such as `^.*FOO.*$\n?(^.*\S.*$\n?)*`, e.g.:

```bsh
pcregrep -M '^.*FOO.*$\n?(^.*\S.*$\n?)*' test.txt
```

The subexpression `^.*FOO.*$\n?` will match any line containing the string `FOO` and the subexpression `(^.*\S.*$\n?)*` will match any number of subsequent lines that containing a non-whitespace character.

### Python Solution

Here is a Python script that should do what you want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf8 -*-
"""grep_follow.py

Search a text file for a pattern,
and output that pattern and the
non-empty lines which immediately follow it.
"""

import re
import sys

# Get the search pattern and the input file as command-line arguments
pattern = sys.argv[1]
input_file = sys.argv[2]

# Set a flag to determine whether or not to output the current line
print_flag = False

with open(input_file, "r") as _input_file:

    # Iterate over the lines of the input file
    for line in _input_file:

        # Remove trailing whitespace
        line = line.rstrip()

        # If the line is empty, stop producing output
        if not line.strip():
            print_flag = False

        # If the line matches the search pattern, start producing output
        elif re.search(pattern, line):
            print_flag = True

        # If the print flag is set then output the line
        if print_flag:
            print(line)
```

You would run it like this:

```bsh
$ python grep_follow.py FOO test.txt
```

```
this line contains FOO
this line is not blank
This line also contains FOO
This line contains FOO too
Not blank
Also not blank
FOO!
Yet more random text
FOO!
```

Comment: a more intuitive regex in the eyes of this beholder is `'(?s)^\N*FOO.*?(?=\Z|\n\n|\N*FOO\N*)'`, but +1

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/FOO/{print "===match " ++i "==="} /FOO/,/^$/' file

===match 1===
this line contains FOO
this line is not blank

===match 2===
This line also contains FOO

===match 3===
This line contains FOO too
Not blank
Also not blank

===match 4===
FOO!
Yet more random text
===match 5===
FOO!
```

A similar variant where `FOO` could be easily changed to something else:

```
awk -vpat=FOO '$0~pat{print "===match " ++i "==="} $0~pat,/^$/' file
```

Omitting the terminating empty line from the default print is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One way can be using `Perl's` range operator `...`:

```
$ perl -lne '
     print s|^(?=.*FOO)|$/."MATCH#".++$c.$/|re if /FOO/ ... /^$/;
 ' input.txt

MATCH#1
this line contains FOO 
this line is not blank


MATCH#2
This line also contains FOO


MATCH#3
This line contains FOO too
Not blank 
Also not blank


MATCH#4
FOO!
Yet more random text

MATCH#5
FOO!
```

In case the extra blank lines are an issue, you can use the below code, where make use of the range operator in scalar context in order to have a peek into the state machine values and perform actions based on them.

Note :

`$/` = RS = "\n"

`$,` = OFS = ""

```
$ perl -lne '
    print
      s{^(?=.*FOO)}
       {
         ($,,$/)[$r>1] . 
         "MATCH#" . ++$count . $/
       }rex 
          if $r = /FOO/ ... /^$/;
' input.txt
```

Here's another method to tackle the pbm, this time using the `paragraph mode` of Perl. We read in records a para at a time and split them on newlines into fields.

Then we make sure to handle only those paras that happen to have the string foo in them. Finally, we print the fields with the constraint on foo-containing fields being treated specially. Even here we deal with the first field differently than the rest.

```
$ perl -aln -F'\n' -00 -e '
     next unless /FOO/;
     shift @F until $F[0] =~ /FOO/;
     push @F, $, if ! eof;
     print "MATCH#", ++$k, $\, shift @F;
     print for map { /FOO/ and $_ = "\nMATCH#" . ++$k . "\n$_";$_ } @F;
' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner that may not exactly match the criteria, but comes close enough for most purposes.

```
gawk '/FOO/{p=1} {if(p) print} /^$/{p=0}' infile.txt
```

First rule sets `p=1` if it sees FOO. Second rule prints the current line if p is not zero. Third rule sets `p=0` if the line (already printed) is blank. Swap second and third rules if you do not want the blank line terminator to be output.

This is a variant which numbers and separates the matches if there are multiple FOO instances not separated by blank lines

```
gawk '/FOO/{p=1; n++; print "\n" n} /^$/{p=0} //{if (p) print $0 }' infile.txt
```